# Kusto query which calculates percentages of values by keys

Tags: key-value, percentage, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to calculate percentages of values by keys. An example would be, given a table like:

```
datatable (key: string, value: string) 
[ 
    "a","1",
    "a","2",
    "b","x",
    "b","x",
    "b","x",
    "b","y",
]
```

I want to get results like:

```
[
    "a","1",.5,
    "a","2",.5,
    "b","x",.75,
    "b","y",.25,

]
```

I understand how to use `as` and `toscalar` to get percentages of values across all keys, but I can't figure out how to make that work by keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use join between aggregations in two levels

```
datatable (key: string, value: string) 
[ 
    "a","1",
    "a","2",
    "b","x",
    "b","x",
    "b","x",
    "b","y",
]
| summarize count() by key, value
| as summarize_by_key_value
| summarize sum(count_) by key
| join kind=inner summarize_by_key_value on key
| project key, value, percentage = 1.0 * count_ / sum_count_
```

| key | value | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 0.5 |
| a | 2 | 0.5 |
| b | x | 0.75 |
| b | y | 0.25 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42O3QrCMAyF74W9Q%20jVJkWdl8KeRKS0WxjdTzq6Tqz48HbO/dwIJgTycZLDKaQLrRqEuEZ/gd5ZTSWHu2wGnDGBaHcNA6GYZJyljG/ovJAK9Pib/Ei3aPeCfmhbafUTITcDuTgB5SHk%20eYYT2S/XgnlRVDFIq7/YYs/HmL2GPXKaIJaU5FpIrQ/nMDQ/NBZU2HuNhk4dGhzJCdLhAzSwwn2U1oBx9FQTPAGjSe1j1EBAAA=)

Comment: Oh, I was so close! I basically had this, except I was doing the `join` the other way, which of course didn't work because I only ended up with as many rows as there was in the 2nd table, which was just how many keys there were, not how many values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please note that I have used `join kind=inner`. I guess you didn't declare the join kind, which is by default **_innerunique_**. Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#join-flavors)